# ¿Cómo saber si un párrafo está vacío con jQuery y ejecutar 2 funciones en el mismo evento?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi código es el siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Jquery</title>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script>
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("p").click(function() {
        if (true) {
          $(this).hide();
        } else {
          alert("Ups no existe texto en el parrafo.");
        }
      });
    });

   </script>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Texto ejemplo</p>
  <p></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Me gustaría detectar si un párrafo está vacío para poder ejecutar mi lógica de negocio, he visto algunos ejemplos aquí: [Enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250292/how-to-combine-multiple-jquery-functions).

```js
if ($('#MyId').length) {
  // ...
}
```

Pero el problema que tengo es que necesito agregar 2 funciones en una funciones e intento hacerlo y me arroja lo siguiente:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

y con este error entiendo que no es posible utilizar dos funciones y para esto investigé más y me encontré con esto: [multiples funciones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250292/how-to-combine-multiple-jquery-functions).

El ejemplo que vi fue agregar una función en otra función pero quiero que se ejecuten al mismo tiempo.

Como podria hace lo que intento hacer ?

Comment: para validar ambos quizá busca  `if ($('#MyId').length && $('#MyId').text().trim().length > 0) { 
 console.log(" Existe Texto") }`

Comment: Gracias por tu solucion, pero dejo de funciona la funcion click :( ya no me elimina el texto con la funcion .hide

Comment: ¿Por qué no marcaste como solución la respuesta de @Dev.Joel, en vez de escribir una auto-respuesta? Es una forma de valorar el esfuerzo que otros hacen por ayudarte.

Comment: porque no me sirvio :( , la de abajo si me sirvio, por eso la marque como solucionada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La validación para este caso sería , si existe un elemento con el `div` o la etiqueta seleccionado `$('#miid').length` y que no contenga texto dentro de este con `$('#miid').text().trim().length > 0`  o otras  opciones , pero dado su contexto está lanzando dicha evaluación si se produjo el evento `click` . lo cuál no seria necesario validar la existencia ya que si no existiera el elemento no se produciría el evento ni tampoco se asignaría el `listener` adecuado. Así que solo nos tocaría validar el texto.  *(Posible resultado final , con la validación de `trim()` al HTML , para tomar en cuenta tanto texto con elementos HTML)*

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click','p',function(el){
        // Si se dio sobre el parrafo , está claro que ya existe
        // tocaría validar si el elemento está vacío.
        // esto validará texto como HTML  dentro de la etiqueta
        if ($.trim($(this).html())){
            $(this).hide();
        }
        else{
          alert("Ups no existe texto en el parrafo.");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
p{
    background:  #ccc;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Texto ejemplo</p>
<p>  </p>

<p> <span>Texto Span</span> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para comprobar si un elemento está vacío puedes hacerlo con Vanilla JavaScript simplemente así:

```
el.innerHTML.trim().length === 0;
```

Y para ocultar un elemento así:

```
el.style.display = 'none';
```

---

Para ejecutar 2 funciones `al mismo tiempo` para el evento click lo mejor es que dentro de la función que hace de click llames a estas 2 funciones, sólo qué se ejecutarán secuencialmente, es decir, una después de la otra.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('p')].forEach(p => p.onclick = function() {
  function1(this);
  function2(this);
});
```